# What is the reason for the speed drop of parLapply in R Shiny app?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, shiny

I have a parLapply function behind a Shiny app action button. Think of it as:

**ui.R**

```
library(parallel)
actionButton("do", "some text")
```

**server.R**

```
optimize <- function(x){do something complex}

observeEvent(input$do,{
  exetime <- system.time({      
    numCores <- detectCores()
    cl <- makeCluster(numCores-2,type="SOCK") 
    outputs <- parLapply(cl,1:10000,optimize)
    stopCluster(cl)
  })
})
```

Every time I click the action button, the shiny app will run the parLapply function in parallel, which is what I wanted. My question is that, the run time for parLapply increases as the I continue to click on the action button. In theory, I would expect that the run time to remain somewhat stable, regardless of the number of clicks to the action button.

A more detailed investigation on the CPU and Memory usage suggested that the longer run time in later runs was actually associated with an increase in the memory usage of the parallel sessions - see below for screenshots. It seems like although I called `stopCluster(cl)`, there was still some information that got carried from run to run.

[First run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSARz.png)

[Seventh run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6z5j.png)

Any thing I could do to correct this undesired memory increase?

Thanks!